# What is the difference between a mesh network and an ad-hoc network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I frequently see the two phrases mesh network and ad-hoc network used as interchangable but from what I can figure out by perusing the web they don't really mean the same thing. What are the actual meaning of the two phrases and are they really interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *mesh network* is a network that has the [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology) of a [mesh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh). There are other types of topologies such as star topology, ring topology and daisy chain topology.

An *ad-hoc network* is a network that is self forming and self healing. It is a network where the nodes spontaneously and continously establish and keep contact with each other. This is in contrast to networks that rely on preexisting infrastructure such as access points, cables, switches and routers to maintain the connections. An ad-hoc network must by physical necessity be a wireless network (it would be rather interesting to watch a network cable spontaneusly sprout from your laptop to link it with your tablet and then evaporate when the tablet went offline!)

An ad-hoc network does, by the definition of the phrase, not need to have the topology of a mesh and a mesh network need not be self forming and self healing.

On a more technical side of things your wireless network card can be put into several different *modes* depending on the hardware and the driver. Most cards support the *Infrastructure mode* and the *Ad-hoc mode*. More advanced cards could support *Access Point mode*, *Monitor mode*, *Mesh Point mode* and maybe other modes as well.

In *Ad-hoc mode* your wifi card is set up to connect directly with the other stations in your cards transmission range as opposed to sending all traffic via the Access Point, which is the case in *Infrastructure mode*. *Mesh Point mode* is an extension of the *Ad-hoc mode* that allows your card to communicate with stations that are outside the range of its antenna as long as there are other stations in between that can act as links.

I really can't think of a good analogy for the topology formed by stations in *Ad-hoc mode*. The network formed by stations in *Mesh Point mode* takes on the topology of a mesh.

Check out the following wikipedia articles: [Mesh Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesh_networking), [Wireless Ad hoc network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_ad_hoc_network) and [802.11s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11s).

In summation I would say that the phrases *ad-hoc network* and *mesh network* shouldn't be used as meaning the same thing. Many mesh networks are self-forming and self-healing and many ad-hoc networks form a mesh but the words describe orthogonally different properties of the networks.